# Codeception: webservices' test methods aren´t callable in ubuntu (works fine in windows)

Tags: codeception

I have this code for a simple webservice test:

```
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Get a token');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendPOST('/token/generate', ['api_key' => <my_key_here>, 'api_secret' => <my_secret_here>]);
```

(...)

I tested it in windows and it works just fine, but when i try it under linux (ubuntu) I get:

`2) Failed to get a token for tenting in validateTokenCept (../../../testing/auth/validateTokenCept.php)

  [RuntimeException] Action 'haveHttpHeader' can't be called

Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->haveHttpHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

If I comment that line, I get the exact same error with the method sendPOST.

Just for completitude, the tests are located in a custom location specified in the conf file:

```
paths:
tests: ../../../testing
log: tests/log
data: tests/data
support: tests/support
envs: tests/envs
```

Comment: Have you enabled REST module?